# how to replace CRLF in python?

Tags: python

```
>>> print 'aaa\rbbb'.replace('\r','ccc')
aaacccbbb
>>> print 'aaa\rbbb'.replace('\\r','ccc')
bbb
>>> print 'aaa\rbbb'.replace(r'\r','ccc')
bbb
>>>
```

I am wondering a reason for last two statment. and I am confusing what

Comment: If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably concentrate on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3. Python 2 was end-of-lifed earlier in 2020, but was originally slated to die in 2018.

Comment: @tripleee Because of the incompatibility, I think they are two languages. I just encountered this problem when I was troubleshooting the problem. I tested the same result in python3. I am not trying to struggle with the language version.lol

Comment: last two versions don't replace `\r` so it moves cursor to beginning of line and `bbb` replaces `aaa` . You get the same with `print 'aaa\rbbb'` without `replace()`.  `'\\r'` and `r'\r'` don't mean special char `\r` but normal string with two chars  `\ ` and `r`

Answer (score 3):

The last two variations do not replace the line return character, so it prints out the original `'aaa\rbbb'`. It first prints `aaa`, then the line return character, moving the cursor back to the beginning of the line, and then it prints `bbb` over the existing `aaa`.

The reason `'\\r'` and `r'\r'` don't replace `'\r'` is because `'\r'` is the line return character, but both `'\\r'` and `r'\r'` are a backslash followed by the letter "r".

Comment: print 'aaaa\rbbb' show 'bbba', you are right. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's because `'\\r'` is literally the character `'\'` followed by the character `'r'`

The same for `r'\r'`. the `r` prefix is used for raw strings.

Both won't match the character `\r` (because it's a single character)